# Jmeter-How to figure out end to end response time including browser rendering time

Tags: api, jmeter, webdriver, performance-testing

I have a requirement to get overall response time including rendering time of browser to be 3 sec.
Do I need to consider Server response time which we get during load test in Jmeter or client page render time obtained from selinium script as the overall response time?

How can I say overall response time with these two inputs?

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter can generate the load with its [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers but won't render the response
2. Browser automation frameworks like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) can orchestrate real browsers but have limited load testing capabilities mainly due to the fact of browsers being very resource intensive

So the "good" approach would be:

- Creating the "main" load using JMeter's HTTP Request samplers (just make sure to [properly configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), otherwise your test won't make a lot of sense)
- At the same time using the separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) kick off 1-2 real browsers using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which will give you the rendering speed as well

You can also use [Duration Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) to automatically mark requests as failed if they exceed 3 seconds